# What is this young shrub with opposite ovate, crenate leaves and reddish stems?

Tags: identification, shrubs

I found this plant growing in my garden in the crack between two retaining wall blocks.

- it's currently about 14" (35cm) tall and has grown this year.
- it seems to branch freely; the one pictured has two branches in addition to the main stem, with no sign of damage to the main stem to encourage branching.
- leaves are opposite, ovate, with crenate margins. The largest leaves are about 5½" (13cm) long.
- the tips of the growing stems are a dark reddish-purple but turn woody just a couple of inches from the tip. The woodiness is the reason I think it will grow up to be a shrub.
- it's growing in Portland, Oregon, USA (USDA Zone 8a).

---

*<sub>Click any photo for full size</sub>*

#### The whole plant

[image]

#### Close-up of the leaf

[image]

#### Close-up of the growing tip of the main stem

[image]

Comment: Have you looked in the nearby neighborhood for similar plants?

Comment: @J.Musser I have neighbors with lilacs and cherries; they're the closest I could find, but neither is quite right.

Comment: It looks remarkably like a young Catalpa, but I'm not at all sure that could be considered a volunteer plant, and the crenation on the leaves seems a little too consistent - crenation is present on some catalpa leaves usually, in the early stages. Was it there before? I can see what looks like the stump end of a thinner stem in the crack in the paving in the top pic

Comment: @Bamboo Which catalpa? [*C. bignonioides*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalpa_bignonioides) and [*C. speciosa*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalpa_speciosa) are the only two common ones around here, and they are much more robust, and also have cordate, rather than ovate leaves.

Comment: @Bamboo The paler patch on the right where the trunk emerges from the crack between the pavers? That appears to be a damaged spot on the bark, not another stem.

Comment: @NiallC. No, if you look a the top pic, just in front of the stem that's growing away nicely, in the crack in the paving, is a little stump, slightly thinner than the main stem, that looks as if its either been cut down before, or has broken off, and it does have a whitish look near the top. Or it may just be a random bit of twig in there, but it does seem to be the same colour as the growing stem. it's a good inch in front of the growing stem as far as I can tell.

Comment: Does *Clerodendrum trichotomum* look like a possibility? It's the closest I've gotten. It's a large invasive shrub from Asia which is spread by bird (produces berries). [The leaves look very close](http://davisla3.files.wordpress.com/2012/09/clerodendrum-trichotomum-leaf.jpg).

Comment: @J.Musser It might be; I think there's one a few blocks away from me, so I'll walk a dog past there in daylight, take a closer look at it and report back.

Comment: Any news here, yet?

Comment: @j.musser It turns out there's a _Clerodendron_ in the back yard of the house across the street from me, but it doesn't have the scalloped leaf edges mine does, and mine doesn't have the peanut-butter smell from the leaves -- I don't know if the differences would be because mine is still young.

Comment: The leaf edges could be a genetic difference, but I'd expect at least a faint aroma.

Answer (score 2):

What about Japanese Knotweed ([*Fallopia japonica*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fallopia_japonica))? There is another knotweed that's similar, not sure I could tell them apart. You'd want to read up on trying to get rid of it, if that's what it is.

Comment: There is some similarity in the leaves, but _F. japonica_ is herbaceous with hollow stems, and I said in the question that this is woody.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, I don't know what I was looking at that showed opposite leaves, as I see that Fallopia leaves are alternate, not opposite. What about a *Clerodendrum*? Not *C. trichotomum*, which has entire leaf margins, but maybe *C. bungei*? If not for the margins, the leaves of the former look more similar.

[Edited] Here is a photo of what's being called *C. trichtomum* with serrated margins. The flowers look right, though it's the first I've seen of that name with leaf margins like that, so maybe it's something else.
http://www.cistus.com/plants_image/Clerodendrum_trichotomum_Golden_Glory___38064.jpg.
The page it is from doesn't have any information, just the name linking to the photo.

[Edited again]Me again. Here is another page with a cultivar of C. trichtomum called 'Harlequin Glory', with serrated leaf margins.
[*http://toptropicals.com/pics/garden/2004/4/4666.jpg*](http://toptropicals.com/pics/garden/2004/4/4666.jpg). Again, no info on the page it's from. I'm actually looking for the ID for a plant from Brazil that has the same configuration and leaf shape but has very decorative white leaf veining, and I came across these two while looking for an ID for that.

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure but I think it could be a hydrangea. below is a picture of one in my yard. It matches all your observations except perhaps red growing tips, but that could be down to the cultivar.

[image: hydrangea]